# What does this mean? function()!()

Tags: r, kaggle

What does this mean?

```
function()!()
```

which came from

```
'%!in%' <- function(x,y)!('%in%'(x,y))  #define not in function
```

https://www.kaggle.com/robhardwick/titanic/my-first-kaggle-script

Comment: The return value will be of logical type against the expression inside parenthesis

Comment: In other words, this function does exactly opposite to what %in% function work

Comment: In R, the value of the last evaluated  statement is returned even though there is no return statement explicitly mentioned here. It is equivalent to  function() { return (!()) }

Comment: The function is a more obscure way of writing `'%!in%' <- function(x,y)!(x %in% y)`, where the intent is more clear.

Comment: This is identical to`"%!in%" <- function(x, y) { !( "%in%"(x, y)) }`, which, as pointed out, is just negating the `%in%` operator

Answer (score 2):

This function returns a logical vector indicating if the left operand is not a match for any element in the right operand.

`%in%` is  a shortcut for the `match` function and this function is a further shortcut. Instead of writing

```
!(a%in%b)
```

we can define this function as such and then write:

```
a%!in%b
```

Definition for `!`:

`?Logic`

> ! indicates logical
>   negation (NOT).